# How to reuse fetched data from API?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm fetching data from a API that returns a JSON object:

```
fetch("api.php")
.then(function(response) {
    console.log("Status: " + response.status);
    if (response.ok) {
        return response.json(); 
    } else {    
        throw Error(response.status);
    }
}).then(function(json) {
    json.forEach(function(item) {

        // 'datas' contains the items extracted from the JSON response
        datas.add(item);


    });
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

If I want to query the data with [jinqJs](http://www.jinqjs.com/) I can change the code slightly to:

```
}).then(function(json) {
    var result = new jinqJs()
        .from(json)
        .where('start_date = 2017-03-10')
        .select();

    result.forEach(function(item) {

        datas.add(item);

    });
}).catch(function(err) {
```

and it works really well.

My question is: due to the fact that by fetching only once the API I actually download ALL the needed data how can I query it 'outside' the `forEach fetch`?. I mean: I already have all the data with one call to the API, I can easily do queries on the data with jinqJs why should I call the API every time I need to query it? Is it possible to query `datas` once the `forEach` has added all the items?

For example, outside the `forEach` (notice the `.from(datas)` instead of `.from(json)`) I could do:

```
var result = new jinqJs()
    .from(datas)
    .where('start_date = 2017-03-10')
    .select();
```

and get the same `result`.

As I'm trying to build a mobile app, this would be handy because I would bind the above code to specific buttons and query the data accordingly and I would connect to the internet only the first time the app is started rather than every time a query is needed.

Comment: If you're fetching JSON, don't you need to parse it first?

Comment: not with `fetch` @evolutionxbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the "JSON" promise to a variable

```
var something = fetch("api.php")
.then(function(response) {
    console.log("Status: " + response.status);
    if (response.ok) {
        return response.json(); 
    } else {    
        throw Error(response.status);
    }
});
```

Now you can use `something` as many times as you like

```
something
.then(json => console.log(json))
.catch ...

something.then(json => new jinqJs()
    .from(json)
    .where('start_date = 2017-03-10')
    .select()
    .forEach(function(item) {
        datas.add(item);
    });
).catch ....
```

Comment: I like your approach! But, is it possible to rethink your code so to avoid using the `forEach` inside `something.then()`? I would like to call only the `jinqJs().from().where().select()` part because inside my original `forEach` I do other things with `datas` such as checking the existence of files using `datas` values that is time consuming and could be done only once at startup.

Comment: Not sure because I'm not at all familiar with jinqJs